# backpropagation with multiple outputs

Tags: artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I am currently writing a Neural Network module and I already understand how everything works with just one output. But when having multiple outputs I was told to sum up the error of each output in order to calculate the loss function, which doesn't make any sense to me, because then we don't really know which synapse/weight is responsible for the error.
For example we have a NN with the shape 2|1|2 (inputs, hidden, outputs)...
So the Neuron in the hidden layer is connected to each output neuron by some weigh. If we now propagate forward and receive an error for each output neuron and sum this error up, each weight connected with the neuron in the hidden layer is adjusted by exactly the same amount. Does someone now if I am mistaken or if I understood something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood, the loss function is usually calculated individually for each output for backpropagation. If you want to know the total error in the output to track your progress, then I suppose you could use the sum of the errors for that.